# Smallest prime number which when spelt out contains the letters P, R, I, M, E

Tags: mathematics, number-theory

So inspired by recent slew of questions based on prime numbers.

What is the smallest prime number when written out (Using the Western numbering system and English) would you encounter the letters P, R, I, M, E in that order. There can be any number and type of letters between them.

For example - one **m**illion **a**nd **th**ree is the smallest prime number where the letters M, A, T, H occur in that order.

Use the [short scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_and_short_scales#Short_scale) only (that is, "1,000,000,000" is "one billion", not "one thousand million" or "one milliard"); you also may not use the less-common terms such as "dozen", "score", or "myriad",  or Indian English terms such as "lakh" or "crore".

<sub>Disclaimer: I have not calculated this number myself due to its huge magnitude and lack of a list of primes that large</sub>

**Hint below if you can't get started**

> The first instance of the letter p in a number is one septillion

Comment: Presumably English only? (I've made an edit to that effect.)

Comment: May one use terms like "dozen" (12), "score" (20), "lakh" (Indian English, 100,000), "crore" (Indian English, 10,000,000), etc.?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin i specified the Western numbering system in the question, thus dozen, score and numbers from the Indian numbering system are not applicable

Comment: "Western numbering system" is undefined, or badly defined. If you wish to limit it to the English used in England and North America, then you implicitly allow "dozen" and "score", at the very least; recall a certain piece of U.S. oratory that began "Four Score and Seven...".

Comment: Also, British English admits "milliard" (1,000,000,000);  are we to assume that large numbers use the "long system" or "short system" for naming?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I had the intent that the numbers were written down as read from their numeric form - 12 would be twelve and 20 would be twenty. I apologize if this was not clearly expressed in the question, and my knowledge seems to be lacking as I only knew of (and considered) the long system for the question.

Comment: References: [English numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_numerals), [Long and short scales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_and_short_scales), [Indian numbering system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system)

Comment: (_Nota Bene: "Short scale" is what is used in the United States; 'one billion' is one thousand million. In "Long scale", 'one billion' is one million million; one thousand million is 'one milliard'._)

Comment: Another interesting challenge might be to calculate the primes in Base 28 (the first base that would contain the letter 'R') and find the smallest prime which contains those digits in order...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First guess:

> 1000000000000000035000061
>  a.k.a. one sePtillion thiRty fIve Million and sixty onE

Comment: N tbbq pnaqvqngr jbhyq unir orra bar frcgvyyvba, guvegl svir zvyyvba, naq guvegl-bar, ohg gung vf hasbeghangryl rdhny gb 997,573,923,793 gvzrf 1,002,431,976,367.

Answer (score 9):

> It is kind of cheating but how about the Standard way to render a Mersenne prime:
>
>  two to the **p**owe**r** of f**i**ve **m**inus on**e**

Comment: Not cheating, this is just an answer to a different question.

Comment: Cheating would be answering: `The smallest PRIME` :)

Comment: @P1storius Last time I checked, 2^5-1 = 31 was indeed prime ...

Comment: @collapsar no doubt about that! Was just making a joke about what a real cheated answer would look like ;)

Comment: @P1storius Oh my, so I didnt get it ... and I want to solve puzzles ... ;)